# Chrome Extension listbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to take all selected items from my "available_items" listbox, and move them to my "selected_items" listbox when I click on the "additems" button. My problem is my JS is behaving strangely. I have played with code for this and found I'm just having trouble getting anything to run right.

**MANIFEST:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "example script",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "redacted",
    "permissions": [],
    "author": "Me",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "pop.html",
        "default_title": "redacted",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon/icon16.png",
            "48": "icon/icon48.png",
            "128": "icon/icon128.png" 
        }
    },
    "icons": {
            "16": "icon/icon16.png",
            "48": "icon/icon48.png",
            "128": "icon/icon128.png" 
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/helper.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
        <img src="img/header.png" />
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="item_selection">
        <select Multiple Name="available_items" Size="10" class="listbox">  
          <option>Item #1</option>  
          <option>Item #2</option>  
          <option>Item #3</option>  
          <option>Item #4</option>  
        </select>  
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
    <br><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="additem" value="&#x1F81E;" /> <br>
        <input type="button" id="delitem" value="&#x1F81C;" />
    </div>
    <div id="items_selected">
        <select Multiple Name="selected_items" Size="10" class="listbox">  
            <option></option> 
        </select>  
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript/Jquery:** -- returns the alert, the dropdown seems empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#additem').click(function() {
        if ($("#available_items").find('option').length <= 1) {
            alert("dropdownlist empty");
        }
    });

});
```

** Why is the dropdown list showing as empty?**
If I take everything out of the document ready function and just do an alert, it works. I can alert the values from the buttons like `$('#addclient').click(function(){ alert($(this).attr("value")); });` so I know my code can see the elements in DOM. If I do a console.log it does not do anything odd enough. **Why?**

Please help me to get past these questions so I can finish setting up the code to move items from one listbox to the other.

Comment: Instead of using $(..).click() use "on" - $("#someid").on("click", function() {})

Comment: When I do `$("#additem").on("click", function() { console.log('test') })` I get nothing so this doesn't really help address the problem I'm asking about. Further, I'm not even able to `console.log('test');`

Comment: @ViralRathod, if you were attempting to employ event delegation there, that won't do it. Those two snippets are logically identical. You'd have to do `$(document).on('click', '#id', function(){})`.

Comment: @shadow2020, it looks like you're loading your script before the HTML. Are you wrapping your event handlers in document.ready (`$(function(){})`)? If not, the elements don't exist when it runs. Either do what I suggested above or move your scripts to the end of the body.

Comment: Attempted both, no console.log output.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the select box by id, using `$("#available_items")`, but your select boxes don't have ids.  To find it using the Name attribute, use `$("select[Name='available_items']")`

Here is an example of moving items between select boxes based on your example:

```js
$('#additem').click(function() {
  if (!$("select[Name='available_items']").has('option').length > 0) {
    alert("List is empty");
  } else if ($("select[Name='available_items']").val().length === 0) {
    alert("Select an item first");
  } else {
    $("select[Name='available_items'] option:selected")
      .remove()
      .appendTo("select[Name='selected_items']")
      .prop("selected", false)
  }
});

$('#delitem').click(function() {
  if (!$("select[Name='selected_items']").has('option').length > 0) {
    alert("List is empty");
  } else if ($("select[Name='selected_items']").val().length === 0) {
    alert("Select an item first");
  } else {
    $("select[Name='selected_items'] option:selected")
      .remove()
      .appendTo("select[Name='available_items']")
      .prop("selected", false)
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item_selection">
  <select Multiple Name="available_items" Size="10" class="listbox">
    <option>Item #1</option>
    <option>Item #2</option>
    <option>Item #3</option>
    <option>Item #4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <input type="button" id="additem" value="&#x1F81E;" /> <br>
  <input type="button" id="delitem" value="&#x1F81C;" />
</div>
<div id="items_selected">
  <select Multiple Name="selected_items" Size="10" class="listbox">
  </select>
</div>
```